# class Amount Not Found paypal

Tags: php, paypal, sdk

I've just started to use the PayPal Sdk to create payments on my Website.
So I installed the Sdk like he told on the official GitHub of Paypal : 
[PayPal SDK Github](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Making-First-Call)

All started well and I set up all the code, but when I ran the script, I got this error : 
`Fatal error: Class 'Paypal\Api\Amount' not found in C:\wamp64\www\UGraphics\payment.php on line 33`

This is my source code :

```js
<?php
require("/includes/db.php");

$q = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1");
$q->execute();

$product = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

require("PayPal-PHP-SDK/autoload.php");
$ids = require("/includes/paypal.php");

$apiContext = new PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
 new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
  $ids["id"],
  $ids["secret"]
 )
);

$list = new \PayPal\Api\ItemList();

$item = (new \PayPal\Api\Item())
 ->setName($product->name)
 ->setPrice($product->price)
 ->setCurrency('EUR')
 ->setQuantity(1);

$details = (new \PayPal\Api\Details())
 ->setSubTotal($item->price);

$list->addItem($item);

$amount = (new \Paypal\Api\Amount())
 ->setTotal($item->price)
 ->setCurrency("EUR")
 ->setDetails($details);

$transaction = (new \Paypal\Api\Transaction())
 ->setItemList($list)
 ->setDescription($product->product_desc)
 ->setAmount($amount)
 ->setCustom($product->product_id);

$payment = (new \PayPal\Api\Payment())
 ->setIntent("sale");

$redirect_urls = (new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls())
 ->setReturnUrl("http://localhost:8000/pay.php")
 ->setReturnUrl("http://localhost:8000/index.php");

$payment->setRedirectUrls($redirect_urls);
$payment->setTransaction([$transaction]);
$payment->setPayer((new PayPal\Api\Payer())->setPaymentMethod("paypal"));

echo $payment->getApprovalLink();
```

Can you help me to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$amount = (new \PayPal\Api\Amount())
```

new \Pay**P**al\Api\Amount()

Need to use upper case for "P" in namespace :)

Comment: XD OMG! Thank you @mochalygin